# Node.js Module class returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my database class which I want to exist only once because I want only one connection for the application and not multiple connections.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var fs = require("fs");
var eventEmitter = require("./events.js");

function Database() {
  this.connection;
  this.poolCluster;

  var host;
  var username;
  var password;
  var db;

  var config;
  var clusterConfig = {
    removeNodeErrorCount: 5,
    restoreNodeTimeout: 1000,
    defaultSelector: 'ORDER'
  };

  var poolConfig = {
    acquireTimeout: 10000,
    waitForConnections: false,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0
  };

  this.connect = function() {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: config.mysqlHost,
      user: config.mysqlUsername,
      password: config.mysqlPassword,
      database: config.mysqlDb
    });

    this.connection.connect(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error("Connection couldn't established at " + config.mysqlHost + " (user: " + config.mysqlUsername + ")"
        + "\nError: " + err);
        return;
      }

      console.log("Connected to mysql server at " + config.mysqlHost + " (user: " + config.mysqlUsername + ")");

      this.poolCluster = mysql.createPoolCluster(clusterConfig);

      this.poolCluster.add("APP", poolConfig);
      this.poolCluster.add("ACCOUNTS", poolConfig);
      this.poolCluster.add("GAME", poolConfig);

      console.log("Created Connection Clusters\n- APP\n- ACCOUNTs \n- GAME");
      eventEmitter.emit("MysqlConnectionReady");
    });
  };

  this.getMainConnection = function() {
    return this.connection;
  };

  this.getAppConnection = function() {
    this.poolCluster.getConnection("APP", 'ORDER', function(err, connection) {
      if(err) throw err;

      return connection;
    });
  };

  this.getAccountsConnection = function() {
    this.poolCluster.getConnection("ACCOUNTS", 'ORDER', function(err, connection) {
      if(err) throw err;

      return connection;
    });
  };

  this.getGameConnection = function() {
    this.poolCluster.getConnection("GAME", 'ORDER', function(err, connection) {
      if(err) throw err;

      return connection;
    });
  };


    fs.readFile(process.cwd() + "/config.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
      if(err) throw err;

      config = JSON.parse(data);
      this.connect();
    });
}

module.exports = Database:
```

In my code I set `module.exports = Database;`
When I want to use Database in another file its undefined. I want to use this in another file and I want to use only instance of that because I want only one connection for the app Im running.

But if I use `require('./Database.js'j;` and use the var it returns undefined

Comment: Unless it's a copy/paste bug, your issue is here `module.exports = Database:`, should be a semi-colon rather than colon.

Comment: When you require Database, how are you calling Database? do you actually construct it with `new`?

Comment: Keep in mind that Node.js actually caches modules so requiring save module multiple times does not result in re-evaluating of the module content (with some exceptions when path to module is different)

Comment: People asked you some important questions to help understand what you're doing very shortly after you posted your question.  An hour has gone by and you have not answered those questions.  You already have a downvote on your question (probably because of this).  When you post a question, please check back on the site several times within the first 30 minutes of posting to see if people have fully understood your question.  Your best opportunity for an answer (the most people that will see your question) comes in the first 30-60 minutes after posting.

Comment: [cont'd] If your question is unclear during that time and you do not appear to be responsive to questions, then people will either just ignore your question or downvote it as unclear and unresponsive.  stackoverflow is NOT like other forums where you drop a question and then come back the next day.  It works best here when it's very interactive and you follow the Q&A about your question and perhaps get an answer within the first 30-60 minutes.  I'd strongly recommend you only post a question when you have the time to check back several times in the next 60 minutes to clarify things if needed.

Comment: Oh, sorry, In my timezone it were 11:00 PM (23:00) and I fell to sleep so I couldn't answer the questions. So to answer the question, I don't call the new constructor because I want only one connection in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the pseudo-classical OOP approach, where you define a Class as a JS function (as shown in your snippet), you would instantiate an object with the `new` keyword.

Instead of `module.exports = Database`, try creating the instance and exporting that as the module, like this:

```
const db = new Database();
module.exports = db
```